# Boolean query is not matching exclusive condition in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

I have the next problem, my data structure has this shape:
`{"editions":['optionA', 'optionB']}`
I need to **exclude ALL** results with this shape:
`{"editions":['optionB']}`

But **include ALL** results with this shape:

`{"editions":['optionA']}`

or

`{"editions":['optionA', 'optionB']}`

Being more clear, I need to exclude all results that just have one entry in *editions* and his value is `optionB` specifically.

I've been trying something like:

```
bool: {
  must: [
    {
    query_string: {
        default_field: "name",
        query: `${params.text}*`
      },
    }
  ],
  must_not : {
    term : { "editions" : "optionB" },
    must : {
        script : {
            script : {
                inline: "doc['editions'].values.length < 2",
                lang: "painless"
             }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

But no results are given. Thanks in advance!

PD: I'm using ElasticSearch **7.***

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing b/c first you referenced `editions` but your script references `sections`. Let's take `editions` then...

Since you're already using a script, you can go with the following:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "name",
            "query": `${params.text}*`
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "editions": {
              "value": "optionA"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "inline": "doc['editions'].size() == 1 && doc['editions'][0] == 'optionB'",
              "lang": "painless"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```